# Combine Excel files according to a common characteristic

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large group of files in a folder that need combining at the country level. For example, one file has multiple sheets of data for Argentina in 2013, another file has the same sheet names but different data and for Argentina in 2014. Another file would have the same sheet names but different data for Brazil in 2013. I need to join the same sheets together for Argentina across all years of Argentina data and have this in one file, and do the same for Brazil that only contains Brazil data.

I have successfully written this VBA code for Argentina which combines the different sheets into a single file (and pastes 2014 to the right of 2013). However, it does not take into account the different countries - I have only gotten it to work by having Argentina data only in the folder. If I ran this with multiple different countries in the folder, it would combine them all together and mix Brazil with Argentina.

Any help or suggestions appreciated, I'm very new to VBA. Thanks.

```
Sub collectData()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFolder = "folder that contains the individual files"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B13:G120").Copy
        Workbooks("ArgentinaTotal.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1New").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B13:G120").Copy
        Workbooks("ArgentinaTotal.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2New").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to refer to a list of the country names from somewhere and loop through them.

Comment: @SJR I can have the list of country names in an Excel column for this purpose, but how would I join that list with the country names in the raw data files and the final processed file?

Comment: If the name of the country is in the filename, you could test for `InStr(MyFile, "Argentina") And MyFile <> "ArgentinaTotal.xlsm"`.

Comment: If all your file names are of the format "countrynameTotal" then loop through the list and refer to ` Workbooks(x & "Total.xlsm")` where `x` is the country name looping variable. Make sense?

Comment: I understand the idea but I'm not familiar enough with VBA and loops to actually implement it.